Best way to queue requests in Azure
Exisiting Architecture in Azure

Azure App Service ASP.NET Core Web Api - "The Sync API"
Azure App Service ASP.NET Core Web Api - "ML Recalc API"
iOS and Android apps

Our apps call the sync service. Some of those calls will mean we need to recalc some ML scores. That recalc can take up to 5 seconds meaning the sync call from the app can take 5 seconds.
I want to remove the waiting for the recalc from the Sync API and simply have it notify the ML Recalc API that a recalc needs to happen.
What is the recommended Azure native way to do this ?
I could create a new Azure Function called "Ml Recalc Requestor" with two functions

POST /requestrecalc that writes to a storage account table
CRON job that runs every 15 seconds looking for rows in the storage
account and calling the "ML Recalc API" when it finds them.

That would work but smells of me reinventing the wheel. I personally dislike Azure Functions.
This might need to handle a 1000 messages an hour. Nothing more than that and right now probably just 100.
